# Allow user to download 1 file per month

Tags: plugins, uploads, membership, file-manager, plugin-members

I am currently using Memberpress for subscriptions to my site. I would like to offer to my members, behind a login, a set of files to choose from but allow only 1 download per month. So I would present a list of 10 files and each member may download 1 of those 10 files per month.

Should I consider using a plugin for this, or rolling my own solution? I've found a few plugins that allow managing file downloads, and even some that have settings that allow only a single download, but it's on a per-file basis. So the user would be able to download all 10 of the files once per month. I'm looking to allow only a single download (across any/all files) per month.